# nginx rewrites with possible query

Tags: nginx, url-rewriting

I'd like a single nginx rewrite rule, hopefully in one line of code because I have to make a bunch of these, that can match and redirect either of these:

```
/short_url
/short_url?utm_source=email
```

without matching and redirecting:

```
/short_url/page.html
/short_url/page.html?utm_source=email
```

And if the query string exists, I want to pass it on.

I was hoping this would work, but no:

```
rewrite (?i)^/short_url /new_short_url$is_args$args permanent;
```

What's the secret sauce?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

URL params are always passed with `rewrite`, no need to explicitly declare them in new URL.

```
## /short_url
## /short_url?utm_source=email
rewrite ^/short_url(\?utm_source=email)?$ /new_uri
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply! Your example showed me that `$is_args$args` are not needed for a rewrite, but that in order to actually get those query strings I have to add something to the source that captures them. So I tried the following, and it worked! `rewrite (?i)^/short_url(\?.*)?$ /new_short_url permanent;`. Thanks again!!